# Proving there exists a unique solution for every $x\in\Bbb{R}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem, implicit-function

Say we have $f(x,y)=x^8+3x^4y^3+y^8x^{20}+y$. I have to show that for every $x\in\Bbb{R}$ there exists a unique solution to the equation $f(x,y)=0$.

So if I understand the question correctly, I take a certain $x$ and proof that there exists a unique $y$ s.t $f(x,y)=0$. So my first thought was to use the implicit function theorem, since $f_y(x_0,y_0)\neq0$ for every $(x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb{R^2}$ and $f(x,y)\in C^{\infty}$, so we're promised that for each $x$ there exists an environment $U(x)$ s.t for every $x\in U(x), f(x,y)=0\iff y=y(x)$, which is exactly saying there exists a unique $y$ s.t $f(x,y)=0$. Is my approach correct?

Comment: graphically this does not seems to be the case. there appear to be two solutions when $x\in[-1.1,1.1]$ approximately and none outside. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lvmkw31e6w

Comment: It is not true. The function is a polynomial of degree $8$ (for $x\ne 0$), it has $8$ roots. Either all are complex (no real solutions) or at least two are real (unless it is a root of multiplicity two that cannot be for all $x$).